# Docker image for building solution with both C++ and C# projects

Tags: c++, docker, .net-core, msbuild, dockerfile

I had a docker file that used to successfully build a VS2019 solution containing C++ and C# projects. Then recently it stopped working.

I've been investigating and trying various combinations of docker images, without success.

I've now got a test VS2019 solution with one C++ hello world console project and one C# .NET5 hello world console project. This does not compile using the following docker file:

```
e# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8

SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Copy our Install script.
COPY Install.cmd C:\TEMP\

# Download collect.exe in case of an install failure.
ADD https://aka.ms/vscollect.exe C:\TEMP\collect.exe

ADD https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\Temp\vs_buildtools.exe
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/channel C:\Temp\VisualStudio.chman
RUN C:\Temp\vs_buildtools.exe `
--quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
--installPath C:\BuildTools `
--channelUri C:\Temp\VisualStudio.chman `
--installChannelUri C:\Temp\VisualStudio.chman `
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools;includeRecommended `
--add Microsoft.Component.MSBuild `
|| IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0

WORKDIR /src

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"] && CMD "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Commom7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
```

The compiler error is
C:\src\dockertest\ConsoleApplications\ConsoleApplicationCpp\ConsoleApplicationCpp.vcxproj(28,3): error MSB4019: The imp
orted project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.D
efault.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Vi
sual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exist
s on disk.

Interestingly, this installs MSBuild for VS2022, despite the aka.ms/vs/16 link requesting VS2019.

Interestingly, this installs .NET SDK 6.0.101, despite the FROM line asking for 4.8

But the main problem is the VC tools are not installed. The folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft does not contain the VC folder.

I've followed various examples but they don't appear to work any more with the recent docker images.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8


SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

ADD https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\vs_buildtools.exe

RUN C:\vs_buildtools.exe `
--quiet --wait --norestart --nocache modify `
--installPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools" `
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools;includeRecommended `
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools;includeRecommended `
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools;includeRecommended `
|| IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0

RUN del C:\vs_buildtools.exe

COPY . .

RUN nuget restore

RUN MSBuild GameClient.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
WORKDIR /Product

ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Product\\WOTS.exe", "&&", "powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```